# Localization_settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, localization, settings.bundle

Just wanted to ask, how to localize Xibs via settings.bundle? Actually, I need to make my Xib arabic through settings.bundle. I have searched a lot for this. Please give me proper suggestions otherwise i need to recode my application and remove all contents of Xibs and do it via coding which would take a lot of time.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713494/localization-problems-in-iphone) helped me for localizing apps in general. See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661619/xcode-3-2-2-and-localization-of-settings-bundle) for localizing the settings bundle.

See too, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113365/localization-of-the-iphone-settings-bundle) - good advice.

Hope it helps, and glad to see you're localizing apps, not enough apps are!